# Chrome is not filling in passwords on a catalina laptop

Tags: google-chrome, keychain

Several months ago I switched to a new laptop with Catalina on it. On this machine the passwords for sites that used to be stored in the browser are no longer being offered. I have to type them in every time.

Some sites do work properly as far as remembering cookies/logins - e.g. *zillow.com* - more of them do not. Examples of the latter include *utexas.edu* and for *chase.com*.  I use *Chase* frequently and can see it in Google Password Manager:

[image]

But I have to enter the password *every time* *anyways*

The keychain does seem to be working: I can see plenty of entries in it. Here is recent history:

[image]

Also: **Offer to save passwords** is enabled:

[image]

Note that passwords *are* filled in /remembered for Safari

So why are passwords not being populated on Chrome?   I am on macOS Catalina with latest chrome Version 84.0.4147.135

**Update** Based on comment from @JBallin

> Go to your chrome settings. Under"Site Settings" - "Cookies" - you see an "Allow" button. Click on the "add" and then add: accounts.google.com (source) – JBallin 3 hours ago

I was looking for how to "allow" *accounts.google.com* .  I do not see an "allow" button

[image]

Update again: now I foudn this under Cookies and other site data - and added *accounts.google.com* (i had previously added 2 sites that are still not working):

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure Safari/Keychain has nothing to do with Chrome. Keychain only works in Safari and Chrome handles passwords separately. Have you tried signing out of Chrome? Maybe a re-install? Also I'm not sure that this question pertains specifically to Apple - it may make more sense to ask on [superuser](https://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: @JBallin  Thx.  This happens only on a `catalina` laptop - not my `mojave` laptop or any other version previously : that's why I'm putting it here.   I might do that reinstall of chrome.

Comment: Here's something to try: Go to your chrome settings.  Under"Site Settings" - "Cookies" - you see an "Allow" button.  Click on the "add" and then add:   accounts.google.com ([source](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/36992068?hl=en))

Comment: @JBallin Thx - I do not see an Allow" button. I am adding a screenshot to the question

Comment: Don’t you need to click on “Cookies and site data” on the bottom?

Comment: Yea - I did find that just after posting that prior message. i'll try again on one of the sites.  I do suspect it has to do with fingerprint authorization: it seems chrome is not integrating that feature properly

Comment: I just logged on to chase.com, closed the tab _and in the same window_ logged on again: the password was empty and I did not get any offer to fill it in.  I'm strongly suspecting there is a problem for chrome integration with the Catalina fingerprint based authentication

Comment: Certainly possible. I haven't tried to repro, I use a pwd manager (which I recommend as it's cross platform/browser). Can you enable accounts.google.com for all sites maybe, instead of just "this site"?

Comment: Ah I did not notice "this site" - good eyes. Will try that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it was a conflict between the keychain and Google chrome account password.
Make sure to allow the use of the password from the keychain, from the popup that appears after a computer reboot.

Answer (score 0):

"Keychain" is an app that runs on macOS. It interfaces only with macOS and iOS apps that come from Apple, such as Safari — it does not connect to or act with software like Chrome that doesn't come from Apple.

Google Password Manager does password management with Chrome, including Chrome running on macOS.

On this stack, the tag "Keychain" refers to Keychain the Apple app, not to password managers generally. You should delete this tag, and substitute the tag "Password."